Assemble product of matrices in Finite Elements
let $A$ be the usual stiffness matrix discretising the $(\nabla u,\nabla v)_{\Omega}$, with classical Lagrangian continuous elements.
Is it possible to assemble the matrix $A^T A (= A^2)$? I don't want to build $A$ and perform a mat-mat multiplication, but I would like to do it with the usual "loop-over-elements" way.
This is what I thought so far: essentially, while looping over all elements, the local contribution of the product of matrices is computed. In the forthcoming snippet, the Tmmult() performs the local mat-mat product for the local stiffness matrices.
I am not able to convince myself that this is actually mathematically true! Does anyone have any insight?
Matrix<double> A_local(dofs_per_cell, dofs_per_cell);
Matrix<double> ATA_local(dofs_per_cell, dofs_per_cell);

for (const auto &cell : elements) {
    A_local = 0;
    ATA_local = 0;

    // Compute local stiffness matrix A_local for the cell
    assemble_local_matrix(A_local);

    // Compute ATA_local = A_local^T * A_local
    A_local.Tmmult(ATA_local, A_local);

    // Assemble into global matrix
}


If you are using this for the normal equations with an iterative solver like cgnr or lsqr, you should really keep $A$ and $A^T$ separate and not concatenate them into a single matrix.

@lightxbulb no, I am not using this for normal equations. I am mostly interested in the overall procedure. I mean, is the procedure above really assembling the $A^2$ matrix?

I don't think it is, because $AB\ne \sum_j A_jB_j$ where $A=\sum_j A_j$ and $B=\sum_i B_i$. What do you need A^TA for if not for the normal equations?

@lightxbulb I don't understand your notation, what is $A_j$? In my finite element application, I need the operator $A^2$. Unfortunately, I can't use only its action, but I need the whole matrix $A^2$. That's why I was thinking about a possible way to assemble the power of the matrix.

The $A_j$ in your case would be the local matrices but extended to the dimensions of your global matrix. What do you use $A^TA$ for?

@lightxbulb In my case $A^T A = A^2$, and I need to solve a linear system with matrix $A^2$. In particular, if I have the whole matrix I can build an AMG preconditioner. Apart from that, could you please elaborate a little bit more on how that procedure is not giving $A^2$? I am happy to accept it as an answer

$$A_1^TA_1 + A_2^TA_2 \ne A^TA = (A_1+A_2)^T(A_1+A_2)$$
And that's also true for $A=\sum_i A_i$. This happens because elements overlap (e.g. on vertices) so just computing local products does not account for the mixed terms from $A^TA$. Regarding the $A^2$ my question is what you are doing specifically that you need $A^TA$. The only thing I can think of is normal equations, i.e., $A^TAx = A^Tb$, but maybe you are considering a biharmonic-like operator. It goes beyond your question, I am just curious from what continuous problem the $A^TA$ arises.

Maybe even more obviously - the sparsity pattern of the matrix you would get fron what you do vs $A^TA$ is different. If you really want $A^TA$ then perform the sparse matrix-matrix multiplication as usual.

@lightxbulb Thanks for the clarification. This matrix stems from an eigenvalue problem. The full story is a bit long, but thanks for the hints, much appreciated!

Maybe you should ask another question about this eigenvalue problem and ask if you can solve it without forming $A^TA$. I would find it strange if that's the best approach; that matrix does not rate to be very sparse and the storage cost would ramp up.

If you write the differential equation is question it might be easier to give some suggestions

@FedericoPoloni It wouldn't be that dense  if these are linear Lagrange elements - it's still mostly fine. In the simplest setting this would just be a non-conforming disretisation of the bi-Laplacian operator $\Delta^2$. This reminds me of the Chladni plate visualisation - for the latter you use the different eigenvectors of a bi-Laplacian PDE with funny boundary conditions. $A^2$ won't result in the BCs for the Chladni plate though, but it's nevertheless related. I am still curious about the original problem - it's much more interesting answering if people provide context.
